# Why does this code - adding wordnet synonyms to index - fail?

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch, wordnet

I am writing this code as part of my CustomAnalyzer:

```
public class CustomAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

SynonymMap mySynonymMap = null;

CustomAnalyzer() throws IOException {
    SynonymMap.Builder builder = new SynonymMap.Builder(true);

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("/home/watsonuser/Downloads/wordnetSynonyms.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = "";

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] synset = line.split(",");
      for(String syn: synset)
          builder.add(new CharsRef(synset[0]), new CharsRef(syn), true);
    }

    br.close();
    fr.close();

    try {
        mySynonymMap = builder.build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to build synonymMap");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    TokenStream result = new PorterStemFilter(new SynonymFilter(
                                              (new StopFilter(true,new LowerCaseFilter
                                               (new StandardFilter(new StandardTokenizer
                                                 (Version.LUCENE_36,reader)
                                                )
                                               ),StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET)), mySynonymMap, true)
                                               );


}
}
```

Now, if I use the same CustomAnalyzer as part of my querying, then if I enter the query as

```
myFieldName: manager
```

it expands the query with synonyms for manager.

But, I want the synonyms to be part of only my index and I don't want my query to be expanded with synonyms.

So, when I removed the SynonymFilter from my CustomAnalyzer only when querying the index, the query remains as

```
myFieldName: manager
```

but, it fails to retrieve documents that have the synonyms of manager.

How do we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If  you do not have your synonym builder during Query processing then the only term it will match is what you mapped to during indexing. And you are not showing that part here.

The best way to troubleshoot this is to look at Admin/Core/Analysis screen (in Solr 4+) and put your text in. It will show what happens with the text after each stage in indexing and queries is run.

You don't even need to run reindexer. You can just define a bunch of different types you are trying to figure out and then run the analysis of the sample sentences directly against those types.